# Fourier series qn determine the fourier series coefficients

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier-series

Can someone please help me with this Fourier series question:

> Determine the Fourier series coefficients of $x(t)$ given as $x(t) =
> > \cos4t +\sin8t+3$?

Comment: For homework questions it is very much appreciated if you show your own work and explain where you're stuck, instead of just copying the original question.

Answer (score 0):

$$x(t) = \cos4t +\sin8t+3$$

Knowing that 
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}[\exp(j\theta) + \exp(-j\theta)]$$
 and that 
$$\sin(\theta) =  \frac{1}{2j}[\exp(j\theta) - \exp(-j\theta)]$$

you can rewrite $x(t)$ as follows:

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{2}\exp(j4t) + \frac{1}{2}\exp(-j4t) + \frac{1}{2j}\exp(j8t) - \frac{1}{2j}\exp(-j8t) + 3$$

- The fundamental frequency is the greatest common factor between the components' (4 and 8), so 4
- The line spectrum (which plots frequency vs the magnitudes of the c coefficients) defines components for $c(0)$, $c(1)$ and $c(-1)$, $c(2)$ and $c(-2)$.
- $c(0)$ is the magnitude of the DC component, which is 3
- $c(1), c(-1)$ correspond to the coefficients multiplying the terms that are 1 times the fundamental frequency, so $\dfrac{1}{2}$
- $c(2), c(-2)$ correspond to the coefficients multiplying the terms that are 2 times the fundamental frequency, so $\dfrac{1}{2j}$

The signal is then equivalent to $c(k) = \dfrac{1}{T}$ (multiplied by the integral over a period of $x(t)\exp(-jkw_ot)dt$, and you'll have five terms.

Hope that helps!